# Mysql Syntax Error (I cant find what the error is!)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql query:

```
REPLACE INTO application (export_date,application_id,title,recommended_age,artist_name,seller_name,company_url,support_url) VALUES (1362564068339,564783832,Eyelashes,4+,Char Room,Char Room,http://,http://ios.charroom.net/,http://itunes.apple.com/app/)
```

I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Char Room,Char Room,http://,http://ios.charroom.net/,http://itunes.apple.com/app' at line 1
```

I cant seem to see where the error is. Can someone help me out?

You must know that the above is an echo of the actual query. All the parameters in this query went through mysql_real_escape_string before being to the query.

Answer (score 3):

Well, firstly you [shouldn't be using](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) `mysql_real_escape_string`:

> *This extension is deprecated* as of PHP 5.5.0, and *will be removed in the future*. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Secondly, you still need to put the quotes around the strings. `mysql_real_escape_string` will escape quotes within the string, but it doesn't add the quotes to the start and end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around data you are inserting in your database.